# Infinite radical. How to show it converges to three?

Tags: sequences-and-series, nested-radicals

Recently i have discovered a new infinite radical with non-constant (that means they are not the same and not periodic) coefficients. But i don't have a strict proof of this identity...
The identity is

$$\sqrt[3]{23+\sqrt[3]{54+\sqrt[3]{972+\sqrt[3]{21870+\sqrt[3]{551124+\sqrt[3]{14526054+...}}}}}}=3.$$

The numbers are (besides 23) $3^{2n+1}(3^{n-1}+1)$. I am interested in how can we strictly prove that the limit is $3$.

Comment: Fine that you don't have the proof, yet you *believe* that nested radical equals $\;3\;$ : why? What have led you to believe so?

Comment: $3=\sqrt {1+2\cdot4}=\sqrt {1+2\cdot\sqrt {1+3\cdot5}}... $ This radical I got by similar manipulations, I know that they are informal, but I am sure in this case it is ok, and Wolfram Mathematica confirms it up to many decimal places.

Comment: And how does that relate to *your* radical?

Comment: Hrm. It sounds like if you actually showed your thoughts, you could have spared me from doing pretty much all the work I put into my answer.

Comment: Saying "new" is a radical move. There are more than a handful where "new" things were actually known decades, and sometimes centuries ago to people.

Comment: @AsafKaragila: pun intended? :)

Comment: Yes, I know, but I have never seen this radical in books/papers or on math forums.

Comment: @tomasz: As if you have to ask. Shame on you. :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila: You were so deadpan about out, I thought it might have been accidental. ;)

Answer (score 7):

Let  $a_0$ be your nested radical, and let $a_n$ be the radical that starts at the $n$-th term rather than at $23$.

They satisfy a recurrence relation:

$$ a_0^3 - 23 = a_1 $$
$$ a_m^3 - 3^{2m+1}(3^{m-1} + 1) = a_{m+1} $$

*Assuming $a_0 = 3$*, the first few terms would be

- $a_1 = 4$
- $a_2 = 10$
- $a_3 = 28$
- $a_4 = 82$

In fact, I conjecture $a_m = 3^m + 1$ if $m > 0$.

Let $b_m = (a_m - 1)/3^m - 1$. Then, $a_m = 3^m (1+b_m) + 1$ and the recurrence relation becomes

$$ (3^m (1+b_m) + 1)^3 - 3^{2m+1}(3^{m-1} + 1) = 3^{m+1} (1+b_{m+1}) + 1$$

which simplifies to

$$ (3^{2m-1} (b_m^2 + 3b_m + 3) + 3^{m} (b_m + 2) + 1) b_m  = b_{m+1}$$

It's clear that if

$$ \lim_{x \to \infty} b_m $$

exists, then it has to equal zero. This confirms that $a_m = 3^m + 1$ for $m > 0$, and finally, that $a_0$ as conjectured.

This doesn't prove that the limit exists, though....

Comment: If you are still interested in my thoughts :
$3=\sqrt[3]{23+4}=\sqrt[3]{23+\sqrt[3]{54+10}}=\sqrt[3]{23+\sqrt[3]{54+\sqrt[3]{972+28}}}$
Coefficients are exactly as i said because of the identity $(3^{n}+1)^3=3^{2n+1}(3^{n-1}+1)+3^{n+1}+1$

Answer (score 2):

Not quite sure what's there to ‘prove’, really. What you wrote basically boils down to:

$$3=\sqrt[3]{3^3}=\sqrt[3]{(3^3-4)+4}=\sqrt[3]{(3^3-4)+\sqrt[3]{4^3}}=\sqrt[3]{(3^3-4)+\sqrt[3]{(4^3-10)+10}}=\ldots,$$

where at each step the term being added and subtracted is of the form $a_{n+1}=3\cdot a_n-2$. Since $a_1$ $=4=3^1+1$, we have $a_n=3^n+1$, e.g., $a_2=10=9+1=3^2+1$. All that's left to show is that each step of the way, in order for the radical to make sense, the result of the subtraction is positive, i.e., $a_n^3-a_{n+1}>0\iff(3^n+1)^3-(3^{n+1}+1)>0\iff3^{3n}+3^{2n+1}>0$, which is indeed true for all real *n*.